# swift Detect the correct textfield to add an attribute

Tags: xcode, swift, loops

i´m writing an input text quiz app, and i have an array of Int where i can store if answer was correct or not with 0 or 1 and also i have 3 textfields where i write the answers, and i want to change the textfields back ground color to red or green depending on the answers variable ,, if index variable its 1 change color to green and if is 0 change color to red.. this is what i have

```
@IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var textField2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var textField3: UITextField!


//change int to 1 if answer was correct (3, ea for each textfield)
var answers = [0,0,0]   


@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

    for (index, answer) in goodAnswers.enumerate() {

        print (answer)

        if answer != 0 {

            print ("ok")

        } else {

            print("not ok")
        }       

    }        
}
```

thanks !

Comment: Your problem is how to change background color of UITextField?

Comment: no,,, what i need is,, if answers index 1 its 0 textfield 1 background color change to red or if answers index 1 its 1 change  textField2 color to green ,, and so......Thanks Mr A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
 var goodAnswers = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
 var textFields:[Int:UITextField]!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textFields = [0:textField, 1:textField2]
 }

@IBAction func btnClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    for(index, answer) in goodAnswers.enumerate() {
        if textFields[index]?.text == answer {
            textFields[index]?.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }
        else {
            textFields[index]?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to have another good answers simply change your code to like this:

Declare new property:

```
var collectionOfGoodAnswers: [Int : [String]]!
```

and in viewDidLoad() method:

```
self.collectionOfGoodAnswers = [0:  ["Hello", "World"],
                                        1:  ["Welcome", "Friend"]]
```

and then implement the click action:

```
@IBAction func btnClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    for(index, _) in collectionOfGoodAnswers.enumerate() {
        guard let goodAnswer = collectionOfGoodAnswers[index] else { return }
        guard let answer = textFields[index] else { return }
        guard let text = answer.text else { return }

        if goodAnswer.contains(text) {
            textFields[index]?.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }
        else {
            textFields[index]?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        }
    }
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Mr A. i have another question ,,, what about if i want to have multiple answers for 1 question, for 1 textfield ,,, ,, how can i do that ,,, i was trying to create an array of arrays ,, or a dictionary of arrays ,,, but so far i wasn't able to do this ,,, thanks once again